# Hello could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong the path is not being detected

Tags: django

`path('product-accordion.html/< slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='prod')` - I think there is a syntax error here could someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.html`

```
path('product-accordion/<str:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='prod')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use html file in urls

```
path('productaccordion/<str:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='prod')
```

Comment: As a matter of fact you can, but it is simply not recommended, since it is "noise".